# Soap UI no longer triggers breakpoints in my WCF service

Tags: wcf, debugging, soapui

I recently made some reference additions to a project in my solution and made some changes to the web.config in order to use another WCF service from within my code without using the 'Add Service Reference' wizard in order to prevent the need to keep updating the reference in case it changes. Since doing this SOAP UI no longer triggers a break point in my service when I use it to test my code responses. It used to work perfectly. What could I have changed that has caused this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure what to be started and debugging manually.

1. Right click on your solution
2. Properties -> Startup Projects
3. Check Multiple start-up projects
4. Action -> Start for your GUI and WCF projects

That will make debugger to attach to these processes and enable break-points.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I do not know what caused it to lose these settings as it always used to work.